# Asp.net core how to get json value in razor page without ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I receive a `json` string from the server side that I want to access its values. This string is not received by Ajax call and I want to have its value in Razor Page.

[image]

In the picture above, two values, `result` and `count`, are received from the server side. How can I have `count` in razor page?

**Edit**

Thanks to those who answered.

I will explain more about the question. I have no model in razor page. Actually, I use `Syncfusion` component to display the information in grid, a json string is received without Ajax.

```
public IActionResult FetchData([FromBody] DataManagerRequest dm)
{
   IEnumerable DataSource = _userRepository.GetUserList();
   int count = DataSource.Cast<UserListViewModel>().Count();
   return dm.RequiresCounts ? Json(new { result = DataSource, count = count }) : Json(DataSource);
}
```

And this is `cshtml` :

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Student List";
}

<ejs-grid id="moshaver">
   <e-data-manager url="/Users/FetchData" adaptor="UrlAdaptor"></e-data-manager>
   <e-grid-columns>
   <e-grid-column headerText="First Name" field="FirstName"></e-grid-column>
            ...
   </e-grid-columns>
</ejs-grid>
```

The table bind well by `result`, but I don't know how to get the `count` value

Comment: Could you please share hows your json data looks like and hows your razor page methods are structured?

Comment: If you actually have JSON, then in Razor: `@{ var x = @Model.JsonVariable }`

Comment: Hello, have you tried the solution provided? Do you still have any concern on this? Let me know if you need further assistance?

Answer (score 0):

> I receive a json string from the server side that I want to access its
> values. This string is not received by Ajax call and I want to have
> its value in Razor Page.

Well, it would be nicer, if you could share your json data format or hows your razor page structure looks like. However, based on your scenario and description you can access your json data directly by calling JSON data in your Razor Page. You would need one additional json deserialization by using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

If the JSON data is part of your model or ViewData, you can access it directly in your Razor Page's markup. Even from raw json data also can be accessed following way.

For instance let's say you have following json raw data

```
[
  {\"key\": \"FirstName\", \"value\": \"Kiron\" }, 
  { \"key\": \"LastName\", \"value\": \"Md Farid\" }
]
```

In order to call above json raw data in razor page you can do like this:

cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    public string RazorPageRawJsonData { get; set; }
    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        RazorPageRawJsonData = "[ { \"key\": \"FirstName\", \"value\": \"Kiron\" }, { \"key\": \"LastName\", \"value\": \"Md Farid\" }]";
    }
}
```

cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}


<p>RAW JSON From cshtml.cs</p>
<pre>@Model.RazorPageRawJsonData</pre>

<p>Parsed JSON value:</p>
@{
    int count = 0;
    var jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Model.RazorPageRawJsonData);
    
    foreach (var item in jsonData)
    {

        var key = item["key"];
        var value = item["value"];
        count = jsonData.Count;

        <p>Key: @key, Value: @value</p>
    }
    <p> Count: @count</p>
       
}
```

**Note:** I am using raw json so I kept the data type as dynamic, but you can keep the type as you wish, either strongly type class or anything you need.

Output:

[image]

[image]

Note: Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), if you want to learn more on [razor page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the question

Comment: Thanks for your update, why don't you directly pass the count value either in tempdata or model property value?